# Big Query Left join issue

Tags: google-bigquery

If we have the next construction I have the issue "cannot be used without a condition that", but I want to receive next flow sup pageview, sum Enroll_Free_Lecture same people who made pageview and Enroll_Free_Lecture should be after pageview, and Purchase same people who made Enroll_Free_Lecture and purchase should be after Enroll_Free_Lecture. Flow: 1-t level pageview second level Enroll_Free_Lecture after pageview third level Purchase after Enroll_Free_Lecture:[image]

```
SELECT
tb1.*
FROM
(SELECT
tb1.date,
  clientId,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT (hits.pagePath,"^([^\?]+)\?")  as page_url,
  hits.type as type,
  hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS eventCategory,
  hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS eventAction,
  hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS person_email,
FROM
  `data` AS tb1, UNNEST (hits) AS hits) as tb1


  where tb1.type = "pageview" or (tb1.eventCategory = "Enroll_Free_lecture" and 
  exists (select tb2.date, tb2.type from(select date, hitss.type as type  From `data`
  as tb2, UNNEST(hits) as hitss) tb2 where tb2.date <= tb1.date and tb2.type = "pageview" )) 

  or (
  tb1.eventAction = 'Purchase' and exists (
    select 1 
    from `data` tb3, unnest (hits) hits
    where hits.type = 'pageview'
    and tb3.date <= tb1.date
  ) and exists (
    select 1 
    from `data` tb3, unnest (hits) hitss
    where hitss.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Enroll_Free_Lecture'
    and tb3.date <= tb1.date
  )
)
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand your question. Can you say clearly what are you trying to do and what is not working?

Comment: Are you using a LEFT OUTER JOIN in some place?

Comment: As can you see on screenshot no, i don`t use left join

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by the comparisons you do inside the sub queries in the `WHERE` clauses. If you comment that comparisons as below, the query will run.

```
with t as(select * from `deploy.ga`)
SELECT
  tb1.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    date,
    hits.type AS type,
    hits.eventInfo.eventCategory AS eventCategory,
    hits.eventInfo.eventAction AS eventAction,
    hits.eventInfo.eventLabel AS person_email,
  FROM
    `deploy.ga`,
    UNNEST (hits) AS hits) AS tb1
WHERE
  tb1.type = "pageview"
  OR (tb1.eventCategory = "Enroll_Free_lecture"
    AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
      tb2.date,
      tb2.type
    FROM (
      SELECT
        date,
        hitss.type AS type
      FROM
        `deploy.ga` AS tb2, 
        UNNEST(hits) AS hitss) tb2
    WHERE
      tb2.type = "pageview" --AND
      --tb2.date <= tb1.date
      )
      )
  OR ( tb1.eventAction = 'Purchase'
    AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      `deploy.ga`tb3,
      UNNEST (hits) hits
    WHERE
      hits.type = 'pageview'
      --AND tb3.date <= tb1.date 
      )
    AND EXISTS (
    SELECT
      1
    FROM
      `deploy.ga`tb3,
      UNNEST (hits) hitss
    WHERE
      hitss.eventInfo.eventCategory = 'Enroll_Free_Lecture'
      --AND tb3.date <= tb1.date 
      ) )
```

Why it happens?
I can see two errors here:

1. You are trying to access an alias table inside a sub query. When you do that, the reference to the table gets lost. If you a run a very simple query like `select (select 1 ) t, (select count(1) from t)` or like `select (select 1 ) t where (select count(1) from t) = 1` you'll notice that the table `t` is not found.
2. Here is where your problem lives: your are trying to compare two fields from two different tables without using any kind of `JOIN`. If you need to compare two fields from two different tables, you must join those tables somehow.

I hope it helps